# Error using lapply to pass dataframe variable through custom function

Tags: r, function, lapply

I have a function that was suggested by a user as an aswer to my previous question:

```
word_string <- function(x) {
  inds <- seq_len(nchar(x))
  start = inds[-length(inds)]
  stop = inds[-1]
  substring(x, start, stop)
}
```

The function works as expected and breaks down a given word into component parts as per my sepcifications:

```
 word_string('microwave')
[1] "mi" "ic" "cr" "ro" "ow" "wa" "av" "ve"
```

What I now want to be able to do is have the function applied to all rows of a specified columnin a dataframe.

Here's dataframe for purposes of illustration:

```
word <- c("House", "Motorcar", "Boat", "Dog", "Tree", "Drink")
some_value <- c("2","100","16","999", "65","1000000")
my_df <- data.frame(word, some_value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) 
my_df
      word some_value
1    House          2
2 Motorcar        100
3     Boat         16
4      Dog        999
5     Tree         65
6    Drink    1000000
```

Now, if I use lapply to work the function on my dataframe, not only do I get incorrect results but also an error message.

```
 lapply(my_df['word'], word_string)
$word
[1] "Ho" "ot" "at" ""   "Tr" "ri"

Warning message:
In seq_len(nchar(x)) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
```

So you can see that the function is being applied, but it's being applied such that it's evaluating each row partially.
The desired output would be something like:

```
[1] "ho" "ou" "us" "se
[2] "mo" "ot" "to" "or" "rc" "ca" "ar"
[3] "bo" "oa" "at"
[4] "do" "og"
[5] "tr" "re" "ee" 
[6] "dr" "ri" "in" "nk"
```

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `[` is still a data.frame with one column (if we don't use `,`) and so here the unit is a single column.

```
str(my_df['word'])
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ word: chr  "House" "Motorcar" "Boat" "Dog" ...
```

The `lapply` loops over that single column instead of each of the elements in that column.

W need either `$` or `[[`

```
lapply(my_df[['word']], word_string)
#[[1]]
#[1] "Ho" "ou" "us" "se"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Mo" "ot" "to" "or" "rc" "ca" "ar"

#[[3]]
#[1] "Bo" "oa" "at"

#[[4]]
#[1] "Do" "og"

#[[5]]
#[1] "Tr" "re" "ee"

#[[6]]
#[1] "Dr" "ri" "in" "nk"
```

Comment: Ah yes! That seems like such an obvious cause. Thank you, Akrun. 
I will accept your answer.